# PHP OCI8 warning while uploading an image to Oracle DB as BLOB

Tags: javascript, php, oracle

I am trying to upload an image as blob in oracle database. I have successfully done this in mysql.but while doing the same thing for Oracle database I am getting two warning

> Warning: oci_parse(): ORA-00972: identifier is too long in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\im\index.php on line 16
>
> Warning: oci_execute() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in E:\xampp\htdocs\im\index.php on line 17

Need help regarding this issue. I have given my code in the below.

```
$conn = oci_connect("DRUG_FINAL", "DRUG_FINAL", "192.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/xx");
$imgData = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']));
$imageProperties = getimageSize($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']);

$query ="INSERT INTO output_images(imageType ,imageData)
VALUES('{$imageProperties['mime']}', '{$imgData}')";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
$r = oci_execute($stid);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to create a descriptor with `oci_new_descriptor()` and use a `RETURNING` clause with `EMPTY_CLOB()` to get a lob that you can stream to:

```
  $lob = oci_new_descriptor($conn, OCI_D_LOB);
  $stmt = oci_parse($conn, 'INSERT INTO BTAB (BLOBID, BLOBDATA) '
         .'VALUES(:MYBLOBID, EMPTY_BLOB()) RETURNING BLOBDATA INTO :BLOBDATA');
  oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':MYBLOBID', $myblobid);
  oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':BLOBDATA', $lob, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
  oci_execute($stmt, OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);
  $lob->savefile($_FILES['lob_upload']['tmp_name']);
  oci_commit($conn);
  $lob->free();
```

Alternatively create a temporary lob with `$lob->writeTemporary()` and bind the temp lob directly into an INSERT statement:

```
$lob = oci_new_descriptor($c, OCI_D_LOB);
$sql = 'insert into mybtab (blobid, blobdata) values(:myblobid, :blobdata)';
$s = oci_parse($c, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($s, ':myblobid', $myblobid);
oci_bind_by_name($s, ':blobdata', $lob, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
$myv = file_get_contents($_FILES['lob_upload']['tmp_name']);
$lob->writeTemporary($myv, OCI_TEMP_BLOB);
oci_execute($s, OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);
oci_commit($c);
$lob->close();
```

This is all shown in the chapter 'USING LARGE OBJECTS IN OCI8' in Oracle's free [Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html)

Substitute CLOB for BLOB as needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry for late reply